# Laravel - how to retrieve url parameter in custom Request?

Tags: laravel

I need to make custom request and use its rules. Here's what I have:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|min:2',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,' . $id,
        'password' => 'nullable|min:4'
    ];
}
```

The problem is that I can't get `$id` from url (example.com/users/20), I've tried this as some forums advised:

```
$this->id
$this->route('id')
$this->input('id')
```

But all of this returns `null`, how can I get id from url?

Comment: Can you post your route?

Comment: `Route::post('/users', [UserController::class, 'store'])->name('users.store');`

Comment: There is no [Route Parameter](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-parameters) in that route

Comment: Oops, sorry, that validation work in update route here: `Route::resource('/users', UserController::class)->except(['show', 'store']);`

Comment: Look your code carefully you did not call rules function, from your route given above you call store function. Read Documentation  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests

Comment: Here's a list of [Actions Handled By Resource Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller). You should be able to access `$this->user` in your methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using resources, the route parameter will be named as the singular version of the resource name. Try this.

```
$this->route('user');
```

---

**Bonus points**

This sound like you are going down the path of doing something similar to this.

```
User::findOrFail($this->route('user'));
```

In the context of controllers this is an anti pattern, as Laravels container automatic can resolve these. This is called model binding, which will both handle the 404 case and fetching it from the database.

```
public function update(Request $request, User $user) {

}
```